# How to send files from Shared Folder to SharePoint Library

Tags: document-library, powershell

We have a ticket system on the network that creates documents in a shared folder (Different computer on our network). Is there some way I could create a script to take files from the folder and add them to my SharePoint Document Library?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to run a script from the SharePoint server that has access to the shared folder. This way all of the full SharePoint object model would be available. The other option would be to use a different server, but then you would have to go through the SharePoint client object model . This requires a more complicated process as you would need to load the DLL's into the PowerShell runspace and then upload using the client object model.

As for the actual script process, a quick google search for "sharepoint powershell upload file to document library" should return a number of results. [Hey! Scripting Guy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/23/use-powershell-cmdlets-to-manage-sharepoint-document-libraries.aspx) is always a good resource.